# Connection to MongoDB Atlas timesout

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to deploy my project and the first step was to deployt the mongodatabase that locally works like a charm.

Created a project and a cluster, set to accept connectios from anywhere and created my admin user, but when I try to connect with Node, CLI or Compass it gives me this error:

> DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "_mongodb._tcp.yelpcamp-owbnc.gcp.mongodb.net": Connection timed out
>   try 'mongo --help' for more information

I'm using Manjaro GNOME.

Comment: Please post the results of trying to connect with the mongo shell. The connection string can be obtained from the connect dialog on your cluster.

Comment: I tried with (mongo "mongosrvURI") and the response is exactly what I posted.

Comment: What is the value of "mongosrvURI"?

Comment: the Uri that the connect dialog provided, with "<password>" replaced with my user's pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a DNS error on Linux! I don't know what exactly caused this, but here's a solution:

Go to the `/etc/resolv.conf` and add other nameservers. Most commons are `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.